# How do you markup a 5-star product rating with FontAwesome using microdata?

Tags: html, meta, font-awesome, microformats

According to Google there are a few ways to mark up a 5 star rating to get it pulled through into search results.

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=172705

None of these cater for using an icon-font such as FontAwesome.

The star rating does not need to be interactive.

Currently the code we have is:

```
<div class="rating">
    <meta itemprop="rating" content="4.5" />
    <i class="icon-star"></i>
    <i class="icon-star"></i>
    <i class="icon-star"></i>
    <i class="icon-star"></i>
    <i class="icon-star-half"></i>
    <span class="visually-hidden" >4.5 stars</span>
</div>
```

The span is hidden from displays but is still accessible to screen-readers.

Is the addition of the `<meta>` tag necessary or even valid?
Google suggests this:

> By including `<meta itemprop="rating" content="4.5" />` inside the HTML
>   block that causes the stars to be displayed, you indicate that the
>   rich snippets parser should use the value in the content attribute to
>   find the rating.

and has the following example:

```
<span class="rating-foreground" style="width:90%"> 
   <meta itemprop="rating" content="4.5" /> 
</span>
```

Comment: schema.org isn't microformats, its microdata. you should try hReview

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it the **itemprop="rating"** can be added to any element so can just move that onto your div.

Answer (score 1):

Using the aggregate rating item properties from [schema.org](http://schema.org/Rating), the best option we have so far is the following:

```
<div class="rating" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
    <i class="icon-star"></i>
    <i class="icon-star"></i>
    <i class="icon-star"></i>
    <i class="icon-star"></i>
    <i class="icon-star-half"></i>
    <span class="visually-hidden"><span itemprop="ratingValue">4.5</span>/5</span>
</div>
```

Removing the `<meta>` tag but adding and separating out the rating value from the total.

Comment: update for 2018 - needs a container div with itemtype specifying business type - also needs itemprop of name and image

Answer (score 0):

You must include itemprop="votes" to google display rating stars in search result

example:

```
<span class="visually-hidden">
<span itemprop="ratingValue">4.5</span>/5
<span itemprop="votes">10</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Can you provide any citations for this?